# jQuery disable and enable based on option selected

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have toggled through a lot of forums and used the suggested way of doing this but it seems not to work. So I am looking for a second pair of eyes to help me discover what I did wrong.

This is a CMS generating the form and I am simply writing a script to do the rest. According to the CMS for jQuery purposes I can interchange the name and id. Below I'll show my jQuery code then the piece I am trying to manipulate. The form already disables the text box it just does not re-enable it after the choice is selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function() 
  {
    $("input:text[name=Other]").attr("disabled", true);
      $("select[name=School[]]").change(function() 
      {
      var chk= $(this).val();
        if (chk == 'Other') 
        {
          $("input:text[name=Other]").attr("disabled", false);
        }
      });
  });
</script>

<form id="ouforms" name="ouforms" method="post" class="ldpforms">    
  <select name="School[]">
    <option value="PleaseSelect" checked="checked">(Please Select)</option>
    <option value="BeachPublicSchools">Beach Public Schools</option>
    <option value="BelfieldPublicSchools">Belfield Public Schools</option>
    <option value="BillingsCountyPublicSchools">Billings County Public Schools</option>
    <option value="BowmanCountyPublicSchools">Bowman County Public Schools</option>
    <option value="DakotaHorizonYouthCenter">Dakota Horizon Youth Center</option>
    <option value="DickinsonAdultLearningCenter">Dickinson Adult Learning Center</option>
    <option value="DickinsonCatholicSchools">Dickinson Catholic Schools</option>
    <option value="DickinsonStateUniversityStudents">Dickinson State University Students</option>
    <option value="EarlyChildhoodLeft">Early Childhood Left</option>
    <option value="GlenUllinPublicSchools">Glen Ullin Public Schools</option>
    <option value="HallidayPublicSchools">Halliday Public Schools</option>
    <option value="HebronPublicSchools">Hebron Public Schools</option>
    <option value="HettingerPublicSchools">Hettinger Public Schools</option>
    <option value="HopeChristianAcademy">Hope Christian Academy</option>
    <option value="KilldeerPublicSchools">Killdeer Public Schools</option>
    <option value="LoneTreeGolvaPublicSchools">Lone Tree (Golva) Public Schools</option>
    <option value="MottRegentPublicSchools">Mott/Regent Public Schools</option>
    <option value="NewEnglandPublicSchools">New England Public Schools</option>
    <option value="RichardtonTaylorPublicSchools">Richardton  Taylor Public Schools</option>
    <option value="ScrantonPublicSchools">Scranton Public Schools</option>
    <option value="SouthHeartPublicSchools">SouthHeart Public Schools</option>
    <option value="SWCHS">SWCHS</option>
    <option value="TwinButtesPublicSchools">Twin Buttes Public Schools</option>
    <option value="WestRiverSpecialServices">West River Special Services</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <label for="Other">Other: </label>
  <input type="text" name="Other" value=""/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use: 
     var chk= $(this).find(':selected').val();

Comment: That's not necessary. His code (`$(this).val()`) gets the correct value.

Comment: yep, you're right. I didn't realize jquery would deduce the value from the parent element. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the `change` event binding is not successful. When tried to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XpZEL/) your code, it was not working.

Then i just changed `select[name=School[]]` to `select[name='School[]']` (watch the single quotes), it is started to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/XpZEL/1/).

I am not sure why, this quotes making the selector valid. Because, somewhere i have read that without quotes the attribute selector should work fine.

Anyway, i too learnt something today.

Thanks.

Comment: oh let me try that solution because it has been acting weird. But then what about embedding...the single quotes within single quotes?

Comment: No, i can be either single quotes with in double quotes `$("select[name='School[]']")` or double quotes with in single quotes `$('select[name="School[]"]')`.

Comment: I wished this would work...still not disabling which is weird

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$("input:text[name=Other]").attr("disabled", true);
$('select[name="School[]"]').change(function() {
    $("input:text[name=Other]").attr("disabled", ($(this).val() == 'Other') ? false : true);
});​
```

This will change the disabled attribute of the text input based on whether the "Other" option is selected or not.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MvQvN/1/)**.

Comment: It can be even simplified to,

`$("input:text[name=Other]").attr("disabled", ($(this).val() != 'Other'));`

Comment: it worked for like a bit then it just mysteriously stopped. I tested it by just having 
    $("input:text[name=Other]").attr("disabled", true);
And it disabled it. I think something is screwing up after that. any hints?

Comment: @Robertpurpose- Do you have other JavaScript on this page?

Comment: no everything is actually everything else is actually being referenced to. For example we have a search one calling a script and so on

Comment: Hmmm, well you can see by the jsFiddle example the code works. Are you getting any errors when you run the code?

Comment: no errors at all just the box enabled. It is almost as if the code wasnt even there

Comment: I'm getting three errors when the page loads (GET http://www.dickinsonstate.edu/js/search.js 404 (Not Found)
tf.aspx:7GET http://dickinsonstate.edu/_resources/js/fancybox/jquery.easing.1.3.js 404 (Not Found)
tf.aspx:90Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL) and the W3 validator found 139 errors and 11 warnings. :/

Comment: Oh that is weird...I just saw those files when i checked my js folder

Comment: Are you using a special widget o plugin to detect JavaScripts?

Comment: To detect the errors? No, just Chrome's console and the W3 validator.

Comment: oh that one is new to me. So i am guessing if those arent resolved, it probably wont work?

Comment: Eliminating those errors will probably resolve your script issues.

Comment: let me see if i can reproduce them.. So for the Chrome, i just download google chrome and this is a built in function?

Comment: Yes. Visit your site in Chrome, hit F12, and then reload the page. Look under the "console" tab of the developer tools (what hitting F12 opens). Checkout what the W3 validator has to say too (http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: so you think i might have missed something that gets this function running on page load?

Comment: Not necessarily. I think the errors on the page may be conflicting with the code that should work (as it does in the jsFiddle example). Have you managed to clear up those errors?

Comment: Well when i went in to see those errors they were not on my side so I am working on adjusting my xsl to get the right output out. But i never saw that cool gadget before, ill need to play with it some more

Answer (score 1):

Hello and first of all I wanted to thank you Robertpurpose for your code, and the others of course. I tried your code as is but nothing happened...so I check if it wasn't a problem with my version of jquery or another scripts...but again nothing....then I played and found that it worked if I delete the [] of the select statement...as follows:
select[name='School']

Hope this helps someone else...